# How to live with both camelCase and snake_case

Tags: python, qt, lint

I couldn't find a good explanation on how to setup linter's or maintain a good code-quality if a module that you are heavily relying on is using **camelCase** and you are using **snakeCase**.

Here is the beauty:

```
def restore_ui(self):
    self.my_checkbox = QCheckBox('check')
    self.my_checkbox.setChecked(True)
```

So do I stick with both cases or do I switch our owned code to **camelCase** as well? And if we wan't to keep both, how do you setup linter's for that and how does it impact code-quality?

Comment: It is a mess but you will eventually run into this working with OS software. The norm should be camel case for class names, snake case for function names. Best I can suggest is to disable the linter for those specific lines.

Comment: It is a mess, especially when I extend a class, the overriden method's  are snake_case and the other's camelCase. Even more confusing, if the next guy add's a camelCase method, then people think, it's part of the overridden framework o_O. I just think to avoid wrong assumptions, to kill one case.

Comment: snake_case vs. camelCase. Yeah, that's as difficult as annoying. Couldn't everybody just use camelCase? I personally like camelCase much more than snake_case. - I recently read a recommendation that snake_case is preferred for Python methods - it's Pythonic. In the case of `QCheckBox`, Qt is originally written in C++. The Python binding just uses the same conventions as close as possible. Both makes sense to me. On the other hand, it's a matter of style and taste, little influence on semantics (if at all). Difficult topic...

Comment: Out of curiosity, (I've no experience with linter) are there really tools which justice identifier styles? (Crazy. I should investigate in this...) ;-) A collaborator of mine tried to fiddle my preferred formatting into VS2017 formatting rules but AFAIK it doesn't cover identifier styling. (Concerning formatting, I failed to do it in VS2013 - it didn't provide enough options.) He is convinced that he got it (VS2017 has been improved concerning this) but I'm in doubt. I must admit that my preferred formatting is a little bit dependent on my personal daily feeling...